# Python - Remove all the lines starting with word/string present in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am trying to parse huge 50K lined file in which I have to remove any line that starts with the word present in a predefined list.

Currently I have tried the below and the output file (DB12_NEW) is not working as desired -

```
rem = ['remove', 'remove1', 'remove2'....., 'removen']

inputFile = open(r"C:\file", "r")
outputFile = open(r"C:\file_12", "w")
lines = inputFile.readlines()
inputFile.close()
for line in lines:
    for i in rem:
        if line.startswith(i):
            outputFile.write('\n')
        else:
            outputFile.write(line)
```

I am getting the same file as output that I initially put in... the script is not removing the lines that start with any of the strings present in the list.

Can you please help understand how to achieve this?

Comment: what problem are you facing?

Comment: I am getting the same file as output that I initially put in... the script is not removing the lines that start with any of the strings present in the list.

Comment: You can try this: ```if any(line.startswith(x) for x in rem)``` which will return true or false

Comment: Actually `for i in rem:` is not correct, consider `[1,2,3,4]`and you are matching somestring that does not start with any memeber of the list and suppose you have a string `3school`, not for the first item `1`, you are finding that it does not match, so you are actually writing it ti output file, which obviously you don't want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently you check if the line starts with the a word from the remove list one at a time. For example:

If the line starts with "rem ABCDF..." and in your loop you check if the line starts with 'remove' then your if-statement returns false and writes the line in your outputfile.

You could try something like this:

```
remove = ['remove', 'rem-ove', 'rem', 'rem ove' ...... 'n']
inputFile = open(r"C:\DB12", "r")
outputFile = open(r"C:\DB12_NEW", "w")
for line in inputFile.splitlines():
    if not any(line.startswith(i) for i in remove):
        outputFile.write(line)
```

The `any` keyword only returns `False` if all elements are also `False`.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `tuple` instead of `list` for `str.startswith`.

```
# rem = ['remove', 'rem-ove', 'rem ove']
rem = ('remove', 'rem-ove', 'rem ove')

with open('DB12', 'r') as inputFile, open('DB12_NEW', 'w') as outputFile:
    for line in inputFile.readlines():
        if not line.startswith(rem):
            outputFile.writelines(line)
```

Comment: Any specific reason to use ```tuple``` instead of ```list``` ?

Comment: Yes. https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith *prefix can also be a tuple of prefixes to look for*

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes this could be caused by leading/trailing spaces.

Try stripping off empty spaces using `strip()` and check.

```
rem = [x.strip() for x in rem]
lines = [line.strip() for  line in lines]
```